# Apache configuration {REQUEST_URI} for homepage

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm running a Django site on aws elastic-beanstalk. I want to redirect `www.domain.com/*` to `domain.com/*`.

I added the following to httpd.conf:

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The result:

- When I access `www.domain.com/something` I get redirected to `domain.com/something`
- But when I access `www.domain.com` I get redirected to `domain.com/opt/python/current/app/myapp/myapp/wsgi.py/`

How can I make it work for the homepage?

Answer (score 0):

Please add following rule that will redirect to homePage.

```
<Location />
      RedirectMatch ^/$  /homePage/
</Location>
```